# How to set time out on Firebase Test Lab?

Tags: firebase, continuous-integration, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab

I'm running Espresso Android tests on Firebase (Test Lab) and it always display the error:

> The test has expired. It has been run longer than the maximum allowed
>   duration and has been interrupted.
>   (Test timed out).

If I increase the timeout to 1h (for example), when I run the tests is displayed the next error:

> (gcloud.firebase.test.android.run) Http error while creating test
>   matrix: ResponseError 400: Given test timeout of 60 min exceeds limit
>   of 30 min.

So, my questions are:

- Is there any option to choose testing on Firebase on Virtual devices to increase test duration?
- Is there any workaround to work with Firebase Test Lab?
- Should I add some instrumentation on my Espresso Android tests?

Any help is appreciated.

Note: 
I have the Firebase plan Free

- Virtual Device Tests: 10 tests/day
- Physical Device Tests: 5 tests/day

Thanks,
xptoGirl

Comment: what happens when you set the timeout to 30 minutes (the stated limit)?

Answer (score 1):

The max test timeout is dependent on the device form you use:

- Physical: 30 min
- Virtual: 60 min
- Physical and virtual in one test: 30 min

In your case you probably use a physical device, thus cannot increase the timeout to 60 min as 30 min is the limit. You can try virtual to get 60 min of test time.

You should probably also take a look at why your tests are running that long. Do you actually have that many tests that you need to run for an hour? Or is there something you can do to improve individual test durations?

Comment: Yes, I have many tests. I have tests that take less than 1 minute, and others that may take 1 minute or more. Running on the usual physical device (which I usually use when I am programming Android Espresso tests), a Galaxy S8, the tests take about 40 minutes. In Firebase test lab I am running tests for a single virtual device, Pixel2. It's normal this timeout?

Comment: Virtual devices are slower than physical devices due to lack of GPUs, which is part of the reason they have 1h max timeout compared to 30m for physical devices.

Comment: If you separate your virtual device tests from physical (that is, use a separate `gcloud` invocation for each), then you can set the full 1h timeout for the tests running on virtual devices. 

Other things you can try are to optimize your tests so they run faster, or break up the tests into multiple test shards.

Comment: Ok. I have no idea that virtual devices were getting so slow... At the level of test code optimization, I think on my side, at the level of test instrumentation, there is not much else to do. About break up the tests into multiple test shards, I put a question hours ago:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58641438/how-to-split-android-espresso-tests-into-different-apks Can you help me?

Comment: And what about Flank 2 (Flank: Smart Test Runner for Firebase): https://medium.com/walmartlabs/flank-smart-test-runner-for-firebase-cf65e1b1eca7?
Have you ever used this tool? Do you know if Flank 2 speeds up the tests by quite a lot? With Flank 2 can I use Bitrise’s integration, without having extra costs? Do you know another type of tools with the same concept (of Test Sharding) as Flank2?